# Define sample size using simple random sampling

Tags: r, dplyr, sampling, statistics-bootstrap, statistical-test

I am trying to run a PCA, but I have too much data (20k observations) the resolution is too low.
I am using sample_n(df, replace = TRUE, n) [from dplyr] to reduce the size and have a better fit.

My question is: what is the best technique to define (or estimate) the sample size (n)?
If I have 20k observations (different sites, different times of the year, relatively well homogeneous), which cutoff should I use: 5%, 10%, 20%?

Could you give me a reference to your suggestion?

Thank you in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a loop with different sample sizes, I dont believe there is a clear cut/off just you could do with train/test (although we have piplines, but you know what I mean the 70/30 cutoff). The only thing I would check is if sample_n is still not too clustered and values are relatively equally represented.

If you are firm with k-means clustering, there we have the "elbow method", which is a little bit subjective where is the best amount of clusters (although we measure RSS), you just have to try a lot of iterations and loops.

You know with neural networks when you have e.g. a million observations you can reduce test set to e.g. 5 or 10 % because in absolute values you still have a lot of cases.

In summary:
I think that it needs a practical test like the elbow method in clustering. Becaue its can be very specific to your data.

I hope my answer is to at least to some value to you, I have no journal reference atm.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I understand that there is no adequate method to define the sample. Instead of using "elbow method", I use screeplot (). Loops is a good option. But how to make a loop? using:       b <- sample_n (a, replace = TRUE, 1000) and prcomp (na.omit (b [, c (1: 9)]), center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)

Comment: As you asked how to estimate samplesize, I thought of: z <- c(1000, 2000, 4000) b <- dplyr::sample_n (a, replace = TRUE, z[1]), where z equals your cutoff criteria and 1 for the first entry (however I would choose a few more steps). In addition you can then loop through prcomp with (b, center = TRUE .....). Then I would give each prcomp a separate output with assign(paste0("prcomp_nr", i), prcomp(...))  where i is the iterator from the loop. DOn't forget to put b into the loop so the iterator can also loop over z e.g. sample_n (a, replace = TRUE, z[i])